# JavaScript eval() not working with variable name

Tags: javascript, eval

why eval() is not executing my code?

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  str = "var foo_" + i + "_bar = " + i;
  eval(str);
}
console.log(foo_1_bar);
console.log(foo_2_bar);
console.log(foo_3_bar);
```

Comment: Because `foo_1_bar` is not the same as `item_2_rarity`, looks like typo question

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/e4wjgh0y/

Comment: Why not just use `var varname = "foo_" + i.toString() + "_bar"; window[varname] = i.toString();`?

Comment: The first time through the loop you create `foo_1_bar`, but you log `foo_2_bar`.

Comment: If you just want to have dynamic variable name, use object key instead of `eval`

Comment: Your last edit works. What's the problem now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `foo_2_bar` is not declared at that iteration (`i = 1`).  You need to put the `console.log(...)` outside of the loop.

*I assume you're playing with js because `eval` is a little dangerous.*

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  str = "var foo_" + i + "_bar = " + i;
  eval(str);
}
console.log(foo_1_bar);
console.log(foo_2_bar);
console.log(foo_3_bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logged variable doesn't exist

```
for (var i =  1; i <= 3; i++) {

    str = "var foo_"+ i +"_bar = " + i;
    eval(str);

    console.log(foo_1_bar);
}
```